# Conditionally highlight X/Y coordinate points in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the below data frame `df`, which contains X/Y coordinate points of gazes, I need to highlight observations with a different point character, **if**

- `G_by == "A"` and
- `aoi != "*"`

How can that be done?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = X, y = Y, color=start)) +
  geom_curve(aes(xend = X2, yend = Y2), size = 0.5, curvature = 0.20, angle = 90)
```

[image]

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(G_by = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
            "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
            "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
            "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
            "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
            "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
            "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
            "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"
), aoi = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
           "C", "C", "C", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
           "C", "C", "C", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", 
           "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", 
           "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", 
           "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", 
           "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", 
           "*", "*", "*", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"
), end = c(336006L, 336006L, 336006L, 336006L, 336006L, 336006L, 
           336006L, 336006L, 336006L, 336006L, 336006L, 336006L, 336006L, 
           336060L, 336060L, 336060L, 336060L, 336060L, 336060L, 336134L, 
           336134L, 336134L, 336134L, 336134L, 336134L, 336134L, 335807L, 
           335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 
           335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 
           335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 
           335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 
           335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 
           335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 
           335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 
           335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 
           335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 
           335807L, 335807L, 336134L, 336134L, 336134L, 336134L, 336134L, 
           336134L, 336134L, 336134L, 336134L), start = c(335443L, 335443L, 
                                                          335443L, 335443L, 335443L, 335443L, 335443L, 335443L, 335443L, 
                                                          335443L, 335443L, 335443L, 335443L, 336006L, 336006L, 336006L, 
                                                          336006L, 336006L, 336006L, 336060L, 336060L, 336060L, 336060L, 
                                                          336060L, 336060L, 336060L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 
                                                          335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 
                                                          335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 
                                                          335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 
                                                          335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 
                                                          335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 
                                                          335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 
                                                          335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 
                                                          335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 
                                                          335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335088L, 335807L, 
                                                          335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 335807L, 
                                                          335807L), X = c(1243.669, 95.667, 1242.195, 1237.877, 176.84, 
                                                                          1234.511, 1234.117, 88.151, 1233.216, 1232.457, 94.804, 1230.706, 
                                                                          1229.153, 1229.153, 175.593, 1228.985, 1226.878, 87.634, 1227.839, 
                                                                          1227.839, 1226.765, 94.367, 1227.273, 1227.115, 175.302, 1227.218, 
                                                                          101.831, 1323.176, 1323.927, 189.132, 1323.616, 1323.903, 94.565, 
                                                                          1324.513, 1325.491, 101.961, 1324.895, 1325.301, 189.329, 1323.407, 
                                                                          1321.983, 94.427, 1325.763, 1322.519, 101.732, 1315.533, 1311.337, 
                                                                          187.334, 1304.282, 1297.268, 92.662, 1292.747, 1291.564, 99.351, 
                                                                          1290.02, 1286.309, 183.758, 1282.175, 1282.24, 91.589, 1283.013, 
                                                                          1282.981, 98.691, 1286.234, 1288.544, 184.078, 1291.33, 1293.779, 
                                                                          92.413, 1292.696, 1291.809, 99.37, 1289.235, 1289.092, 184.156, 
                                                                          1288.734, 1273.203, 90.943, 1253.726, 1260.098, 96.931, 1260.359, 
                                                                          1257.307, 179.615, 1256.716, 1254.997, 89.643, 1251.844, 1248.95, 
                                                                          96.073, 1247.923, 1246.787, 1246.787, 178.112, 1245.294, 1243.859, 
                                                                          88.847, 1243.662, 1243.669, 95.667, 1242.195), Y = c(777.273, 
                                                                                                                               59.79, 774.108, 776.986, 110.998, 770.954, 772, 55.143, 774.301, 
                                                                                                                               775.964, 59.69, 773.456, 773.797, 773.797, 110.542, 773.772, 
                                                                                                                               770.084, 55.006, 774.858, 774.858, 775.519, 59.655, 772.968, 
                                                                                                                               770.372, 110.053, 773.748, 57.568, 751.105, 749.93, 107.133, 
                                                                                                                               752.105, 753.008, 53.786, 756.299, 753.915, 57.993, 748.945, 
                                                                                                                               729.043, 104.149, 712.812, 700.113, 50.008, 692.636, 696.91, 
                                                                                                                               53.608, 716.137, 736.1, 105.157, 778.374, 806.545, 57.61, 845.488, 
                                                                                                                               859.495, 66.115, 873.99, 875.468, 125.067, 882.603, 885.596, 
                                                                                                                               63.257, 891.389, 892.791, 68.676, 886.554, 880.736, 125.819, 
                                                                                                                               872.607, 858.378, 61.313, 857.117, 852.118, 65.548, 846.301, 
                                                                                                                               838.256, 119.751, 828.451, 820.558, 58.611, 808.984, 797.231, 
                                                                                                                               61.325, 793.757, 781.964, 111.709, 785.577, 781.139, 55.796, 
                                                                                                                               783.966, 785.837, 60.449, 784.229, 783.958, 783.958, 111.994, 
                                                                                                                               782.057, 779.151, 55.654, 775.096, 777.273, 59.79, 774.108), 
X2 = c(1243.66189483224, 1243.66883234387, 95.6670013345061, 
       1242.19483142949, 1237.87709164453, 176.839900986528, 1234.51104300381, 
       1234.11705609311, 88.1511101828323, 1233.21606530819, 1232.45715230831, 
       94.8039988270749, 1230.70598058442, 1230.70598058442, 1229.15292534967, 
       175.593125123791, 1228.9848048029, 1226.87810112289, 87.6341372241518, 
       87.6341372241518, 1227.83909935593, 1226.76511946295, 94.3670858203068, 
       1227.27298004515, 1227.11492296824, 175.302086461988, 1323.79892919052, 
       101.831021772147, 1323.17592440006, 1323.92684552008, 189.132121834381, 
       1323.61585397317, 1323.90280510072, 94.56505657988, 1324.51291745075, 
       1325.49105683181, 101.960949811854, 1324.89491124089, 1325.30093524044, 
       189.328829803444, 1323.40713089893, 1321.98310507179, 94.4271855637074, 
       1325.7630361234, 1322.51913334302, 101.731967529216, 1315.53317358878, 
       1311.33718991605, 187.333898291988, 1304.28199666308, 1297.26804147008, 
       92.6620912784154, 1292.74681294108, 1291.56419092307, 99.3508169013675, 
       1290.02002752532, 1286.30914208363, 183.757865244747, 1282.17501508966, 
       1282.23999018958, 91.5889054423468, 1283.01284906486, 1282.9808053375, 
       98.6908130934981, 1286.23411914241, 1288.54395655155, 184.078193889676, 
       1291.32992989582, 1293.77919501497, 92.41298416139, 1292.69594686011, 
       1291.80915809094, 99.3699325651525, 1289.23485285336, 1289.09190975334, 
       184.156099798135, 1288.73387881886, 1273.20300033474, 90.9429781927355, 
       1253.7259370158, 1260.09792226961, 96.9308522702317, 1260.35916480768, 
       1257.30710494573, 179.614899727147, 1256.71588691427, 1254.99700913875, 
       89.6430871373629, 1251.84388384532, 1248.95016840013, 96.0728526419362, 
       1247.92282438357, 1247.92282438357, 1246.78712512198, 178.111886498614, 
       1245.29416169103, 1243.85909976149, 88.8470108827844, 1243.66189483224, 
       1243.66883234387, 95.6670013345061), Y2 = c(775.096003621103, 
                                                   777.273177350233, 59.7901595853619, 774.107893094004, 776.985944027946, 
                                                   110.99807873647, 770.953840915702, 772.000199414828, 55.1431811459051, 
                                                   774.301181386419, 775.9638183054, 59.69007718172, 773.455898078222, 
                                                   773.455898078222, 773.79709590365, 110.542145125455, 773.772061456105, 
                                                   770.084108384831, 55.0061749136115, 55.0061749136115, 774.857857706126, 
                                                   775.51918233125, 59.6550478472371, 772.967932265382, 770.371948544008, 
                                                   110.053186762679, 748.379029024009, 57.5681795608339, 751.1049568804, 
                                                   749.929971154964, 107.133040778729, 752.104878232658, 753.008096167124, 
                                                   53.7859071495418, 756.299052950505, 753.914827999186, 57.9928270750857, 
                                                   748.945070462061, 729.043082183849, 104.149168961676, 712.812167185487, 
                                                   700.113198010282, 50.0078318713561, 692.635941845823, 696.910184435912, 
                                                   53.6080365216881, 716.136967995683, 736.099974871014, 105.157122172931, 
                                                   778.3741732116, 806.545005739786, 57.6098232292008, 845.487946942426, 
                                                   859.494856227266, 66.1148991965545, 873.989863336016, 875.468070835636, 
                                                   125.067128197619, 882.602897095131, 885.596027338574, 63.2571851901215, 
                                                   891.388950647327, 892.79119575019, 68.6759235775765, 886.554184379028, 
                                                   880.73603209406, 125.819140012119, 872.607060620682, 858.378025940963, 
                                                   61.3131185208026, 857.116943492134, 852.118019248929, 65.547811049463, 
                                                   846.300940567356, 838.256032941651, 119.751197021659, 828.451154309676, 
                                                   820.557939000032, 58.6111491946813, 808.98389484884, 797.230990410233, 
                                                   61.3249809184768, 793.757071222443, 781.963915012922, 111.709084061567, 
                                                   785.577101762583, 781.138891117995, 55.7959754236434, 783.96589331449, 
                                                   785.836978196536, 60.4488589718108, 784.228949244354, 784.228949244354, 
                                                   783.957825419226, 111.993943230985, 782.057127807483, 779.151086618391, 
                                                   55.6538168312422, 775.096003621103, 777.273177350233, 59.7901595853619
       )), row.names = c(NA, -101L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                               "data.frame"))
```

**EDIT**:

I've found this solution:

```
ggplot(eet_A_aoi, aes(x = X, y = Y, color=start)) +
  geom_curve(aes(xend = X2, yend = Y2), size = 0.5, curvature = 0.20, angle = 90)+
  geom_point(data = eet_A_aoi %>% filter(G_by=="A" & aoi != "*"), aes(x = X, y = Y, color = start), 
             shape = 4, size = 4, col = "red")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` the dataframe and then add multiple layers of geoms for the subsets:

```r
spl <- split(df, ~ G_by == "A" & aoi != "*")

ggplot() +
  geom_curve(data = spl[[1]], 
             aes(x = X, y = Y, color = start, xend = X2, yend = Y2), 
             size = 0.5, curvature = 0.20, angle = 90) +
  geom_curve(data = spl[[2]], 
             aes(x = X, y = Y, color = start, xend = X2, yend = Y2), 
             size = 0.5, curvature = 0.20, angle = 90) +
  geom_point(data = spl[[1]], aes(x = X, y = Y, color = start), 
             shape = 4, size = 4)
```

[image]